# Index on JSON field with dynamic keys

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.5, json

I'm on PG 9.5 and I have a table Visitors(id, data::json)

Example:

```
Visitor(id: 1, data: {name: 'Jack', age: 33, is_user: true })
```

I'd like to perform queries like

- Give me all visitors named Jack and age > 25
- Give me all visitors who are users, but where name is unspecified
  (key not in json)

The keys inside the data column user-specified and as such are dynamic.

Which index makes the most sense in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Alter your JSON column to be jsonb and try a gin index on the data field like:

```
create index ginner on Visitor using gin(data);
```

They can be slow to create and big but will allow arbitrary queries. Here's a demonstration:

https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/

Comment: Does GIN speed up range queries (>, <, >=, <=) or only exact matches (=)? I fear that the current implementation of GIN is only useful for exact matches...

Comment: Ok, I have found the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) about this: GIN supports only equality operators (and not <, >) in the current PG implementation (v13). See also [JSON indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

Answer (score 3):

> Give me all visitors named Jack and age > 25
>
> Give me all visitors who are users, but where name is unspecified (key not in json)

I assume you've read the docs. The answer is you can not do this. There are two types of index classes that can work on JSONB using `GIST` and `GIN`: the `jsonb_path_ops`, and `jsonb_ops` (the default).

```
CREATE INDEX idxginp ON api USING GIN (jdoc jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX idxgin ON api USING GIN (jdoc);
```

Using `jsonb_ops` I believe you can test for the non-existence of a value. However, in neither of these can you test for anything but arbitrary *containment*. [From the docs on JSONB indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with top-level key-exists operators ?, ?& and ?| operators and path/value-exists operator @>.

Find out what those operators do for the type in the [JSON-function docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

If you need to know if Jack is older than 25. You'll have to create a btree on `data->>'age'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for first query

`create index IX_1 on Visitor using BTree((data->>'age')::INT)`

And this for second query

`create index IX_2 on Visitor using BTree((data->>'is_user')::INT, (data->>'Name'))`

Comment: He said the keys are user-generated so that won't cover new cases.